# I have some issue about WebView

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I can't use WebView correctly. When I run my app there is "What to use" window and buttons "Browser, Chrome, Sorting" On Clicking "Отмена"/"Cancel" there is nothing happen. There are no errors in my code and I really don't know how to use WebView correctly. Please help me. ["What to use" window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a38Jg.png)

But I add WebView and I want to show everything in it. There is my code:

**Main_Activity.java**

```
    package com.admin.zabroshki;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.webkit.WebView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }

        @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // получим идентификатор выбранного пункта меню
            int id = item.getItemId();

            String urlVK = new String("https://vk.com/zabroshkiborika");
            String urlInstagram = new 
    String("https://instagram.com/zabroshkiborika");

            WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

            switch (id)
            {
                case R.id.urlVK:
                    view.loadUrl(urlVK);
                    break;
                case R.id.Instagram:
                    view.loadUrl(urlInstagram);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.admin.zabroshki.MainActivity">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What happens when you click on "Chrome" for example?

Comment: Have you tried another website? Why does **load with overview** and **use wide viewport**? Have you tried commenting out these lines? Also... "view" could not be a good word to use...

Comment: @MehdiB. The Chrome browser opens my website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try this.

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl("https://vk.com/zabroshkiborika");
```