# How to open url in webview activity

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

How to open Url in Webview activity

Hi,

i want to open link in WebView activity right now my code is scan barcode & open link directly to browser but
i want to change it and open in Webview 
how can i do this please help me to fix this issue

thanks

here is code of BarcodeScannerActivity

```
   public class BarcodeScannerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String scanContent;
    String scanFormat;
    TextView textView;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_barcode_scanner);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(BarcodeScannerActivity.this);
                scanIntegrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                scanIntegrator.setBeepEnabled(true);

                //enable the following line if you want QR code
                //scanIntegrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);

                scanIntegrator.setCaptureActivity(CaptureActivityAnyOrientation.class);
                scanIntegrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
                scanIntegrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
                scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            if (scanningResult.getContents() != null) {
                scanContent = scanningResult.getContents().toString();
                scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName().toString();
            }

            Toast.makeText(this, scanContent + "   type:" + scanFormat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            textView.setText(scanContent + "    type:" + scanFormat);



            Intent browseintent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/index.php?iduser="+ scanContent));
            startActivity(browseintent);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing scanned", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Webview Activity Code

```
        public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            Button b1;
            EditText ed1;

            private WebView wv1;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

                b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
                ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

                wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
                wv1.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

                b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String url = ed1.getText().toString();

                        wv1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
                        wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                        wv1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
                        wv1.loadUrl(url);
                    }
                });
            }

            private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try this with similar issues with webview:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49100156/4904995

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the following code

```
Intent browseintent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
  Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/index.php?iduser="+ scanContent));
  startActivity(browseintent);
```

with below code

```
Intent browseintent=new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
browseintent.putExtra("url","http://www.example.com/index.php?iduser="+ scanContent);
startActivity(browseintent);
```

This will open the secondactivity with url in intent extras. You can set it to your edittext or you can use it directly to your webview.
You can receive the url in the second activity using the following code

```
String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
```

You can use it in your button click as follows

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");

                    wv1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
                    wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    wv1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
                    wv1.loadUrl(url);
                }
            });
```

Comment: sorry e is capital make it putExtra

Comment: when i open second activity it will show error keeps stopping  close app

Comment: as per your code webview is loaded when you click on the button in same layout. If you want to load the webview directly when opening activity you need to give the code outside the onclick of the button

Comment: yes i want to load the webview directly i want to remove button also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167080/discussion-between-ramees-and-user1833487).

Answer (score 2):

You try this, it should open link with webview:

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl("https://vk.com/zabroshkiborika");
```